# MonoMac - move UI files to class library

Tags: xcode, monomac

On MonoMac, is it possible to move at least my ViewControllers (and, ideally, my .xib files) into a class library project?

In attempting to do this, my XCode integration gets broken.

For example, in the default project:

- Moving MainWindowController.cs to a class library means that it no longer compiles (because it can't see the MainWindow class)
- So I move MainWindow.cs and MainWindow.designer.cs into my class library too. Now, my solution compiles but doesn't run - I get the following on the console:

*Unknown Window class MainWindow in Interface Builder file, creating generic Window instead*

And crash on a null pointer trying to cast MainWindow

So it's apparent that I've broken the link between my .xib and my managed code. Of course, moving the .xib itself doesn't help - once it's in a class library project, I lose all the 'magic' (e.g. double clicking opens the file as text inside MD, rather than XCode).

Of course, there are workarounds that I can apply here - Keeping my controllers as thin as absolutely possible and trying to structure them as very thin wrappers on top of logic in my class library. But it would be great if I could actually move the controllers. A dive into the MonoMac source didn't help, obviously it's very complex.

I should note, that I have had success structuring a MonoTouch project in this fashion. Of course the difference was, it didn't use .xib files...

I already posted on the Mono forum, but without any response (http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/MonoMac-project-structure-tp4657231.html). Hopefully my question will get greater visibility here.

---

EDIT:

This still doesn't work. Although latest MonoDevelop lets me create and compile a solution in this way, the actual output doesn't work as expected. The debugger never attaches. Removing the MainWindow definition from the MonoMac project (leaving your custom window definitions in the library project) results in the same error.

---

Comment: This should - in theory - work with the latest version of MonoDevelop.  To get the 'magic', you need to create your library project as a normal MonoMac Project, then delete the Main.cs and other generated files and change the project type to library.  However, I just tested this and I'm getting an error because the .xib files are not included in the app package.  See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3611

Comment: @MartinBaulig Thanks for the reply and the heads up on the bug! I will continue to monitor it. I would love to be able to create a 'MonoMac Class Library' project :)

Comment: I see from the bug that this should now be fixed... I'm able to build MD from master, but can't figure out how to build and integrate MonoMac at the same time (compiling the 'select' profile doesn't let me choose MonoMac, MonoMac won't build from within the MonoDevelop.mdw, and manually copying over my existing MonoMac add in breaks MD). So I guess I'll just have to wait for a 3.0.6 release to test this...

Comment: @MartinBaulig As per my edit, this is still broken. The project structure can be created, but it is worthless. To test this out, try the sample attached to the bug - when you run the app, it is 'MainWindow' that gets created, not 'MySpecialWindow'. Should this be a new bug on Bugzilla? Or is there a mechanism to reopen this one?